# How do I use a click event to navigate to another vue route with paameters

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatables

I am using bootstrap-table-vue, in the action button, I want to trigger an onClick event which will navigate to another route.

```
{
    field: 'action',
    title: 'Actions',
    align: 'center',
    clickToSelect: false,
    render: function(e, value, row){},
    formatter: function (e, value, row){
        return '<a class="btn btn-sm show" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><i class="fas fa-edit text-info"></i></a>'
    },
    events: {
        'click .show': function (e, value, row){
            return this.$router.push({name:'tourist-site-details', params: {id:row.id}})
            //return this.router.push({name:'tourist-site-details', params: {id:row.id}})
            //none of the above options work
        },
    }
}
```

when i click on the action button, nothing happens

```
return window.location.assign('/tourist-site/details/'+row.id)
```

the above code works though but it will refresh the page, which I don't really like.
is there anything am not doing right?

Answer (score 1):

The function in the event trigger is called in the global namespace so you have to first access the Vue instance.

first assign your Vue instance to a variable when you instantiate it:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  ...
})
```

then access it from that variable:

```
events: {
   'click .show': function (e, value, row){
        vm.$router.push('/path/'+value)
    },
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/yrsjv0hu/)

Alternatively you could use vue-bootstrap which allows you to include vue components within its predefined slots:

```
<b-table>
<template v-slot:cell(action)="data">
   <router-link :to="'/tourist-site/details/'+row.id" class="btn btn-sm show">
      <i class="fas fa-edit text-info"></i>
    </router-link>
</template>
</b-table>
```

Comment: It doesn't work either, this is rendered as it is instead of being converted to the normal html anchor tag, so when I click on it absolutely nothing happens

Comment: In that case, best to edit the template. I've updated my answer. You are using bootstrap-vue right?

Comment: this is how my table component is

    `<div class="card-body table table-responsive table-striped p-0">
                        <bootstrap-table :data="sites" :options="myOptions" :columns="myColumns" sticky-header responsive />
                    </div>`

can you please edit this one to the correct format

Comment: Do you have a link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this plugin as it is primarily written for use with jQuery and allows only limited interaction with Vue in terms of events, slots ect.. Bootstrap-Vue will give you far more control, and will work with my answer:  https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/